# get element by data attribute

Tags: html, jquery

I have this html structure:

```
<table id="table">
   <tr data-id="3">
      <td>08.09.2021</td>
      <td><div class="btnDelete">Delete</div></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

and this onclick function:

```
var myID = 3;
$(".btnDelete").click(function() {
    
   console.log(
      $('#table').parents('tr').find("[data-id='" + myID + "']").html()
   )

})
```

Result will be "undefined".

```js
var myID = 3;
$(".btnDelete").click(function() {
    
   console.log(
      $('#table').parents('tr').find("[data-id='" + myID + "']").html()
   )

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
   <tr data-id="3">
      <td>08.09.2021</td>
      <td><div class="btnDelete">Delete</div></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

I would like to get the html part of `<tr data-id="3">` and search this element by the data attribute "data-id". But my way doesn't work.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: `parents()` goes up the DOM, not down. Just remove that method: `$('#table').find("[data-id='" + exportID + "']").html()`

Comment: *Always* debug your selectors - seems 90% (anecdotal) of the time people ask a question like *.html() not working* and they just have the wrong selector(s).  `console.log($("#table").length, $('#table').parents('tr').length, $('#table').parents('tr').find("[data-id='" + myID + "']").length)` would *very quickly* tell you where your issue is (assuming you don't have a nested table, but then you wouldn't know you had an error as it work still "work")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your error:

```
  $('#table').parents('tr').find("[data-id='" + myID + "']").html()
```

That should be:

```
  $('#table').find("[data-id='" + myID + "']").html()
```

Answer (score 0):

The element with the id `table` doesn't have any ancestors (the parents function searches for ancestors not just parents) that are `tr` elements in the HTML you've provided.

Get rid of that clause.